# Issue with multilevel bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

when I select the child drop-down menu item, the hole dropdown disappears. I want only selected drop-down is disappearing and it won't hide the parent dropdown.

```
 <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

please refer to the link below . You can do some changes on your css.

```
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ramya0072/c2dg56t7/6/)

Comment: it also not work... actually, I want parent drop-down won't hide when I click on child dropdown, @ramya0072